# Does using the `__irq` specified for a function pointer declaration do anything?

Tags: c, arm

I have to do a bit of embedded programming for a project and am learning by looking at some other projects. I found the following code that declares the vector table:

```
typedef void (*const vect_t)(void) __irq;

vect_t vector_table[]
__attribute__ ((section("vectors"))) = {
  (vect_t) (RAM_BASE + RAM_SIZE),
  (vect_t) Reset_Handler,
  // ...
};
```

The reset handler is declared as follows:

```
void Reset_Handler(void) {
  // ... no interesting
}
```

I read up on `__irq` and the ARM compiler docs state the following:

> The compiler generates function entry and exit sequences suitable for
> use in an interrupt handler when this attribute is present.

I'm guessing that `vect_t` is supposed to be a pointer to `void` functions that take no arguments, that are suitable to be used as interrupt handlers. This seems strange to me, as `__irq` should just be a compiler hint for the implementation, but not something that contributes to the type of a function (like arguments or return type do).

My assumption is that `__irq` should have been used on `Reset_Handler` (and on all other interrupt handlers) and not in the type definition. Is this correct?

---

Please note that I am not asking what `__irq` does. I understand that this is not part of the C standard and that it is an ARM compiler extension. I also understand that the code that is produced when using it depends on the CPU architecture.

Comment: If you remove the casting of `Reset_Handler` when initializing `vector_table`, do you get an error or warning message? That error or warning could be just because the declaration of `Reset_Handler` doesn't have that `__irq` specifier. In your case you shouldn't really need to cast the function pointers used to initialize `vector_table`, and doing so to silence the compiler indicates a problem with the code.

Comment: This might stem from a misunderstanding of the one who wrote the type definition. -- However, a simple test with your compiler should show, if this keyword is needed on pointers of such functions, too. It might be that the compiler marks even the address.

Comment: kind of disturbing IMO to do the vector table in C, but YMMV.   Please read the arm documentation to understand that there is no reason to expect any special instructions or data for the cortex-m.  Also tag the question appropriately as well as provide the minimum amount of information (what arm core cortex-m? for example)

Comment: what the compiler adds is target (mips, x86, powerpc, etc) specific, but generally there are additional requirements like special return instruction, and preserving the state (registers and flags).  Here again for the cortex-m the core design takes care of this, most others do not

Comment: the vector table and what you wrap the handler with are two separate topics.  vector/exception solution is architecture specific.   what matters for the cortex-m is that the lsbit is set and a compiled function will set the right flags for the linker to know to set that bit (for gnu tools and ideally others too).

Comment: you need to also specify the compiler as this is compiler specific not a C thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, interrupt service routines (ISR) use different instructions for returning. A normal function just uses a "return from subroutine" instruction which pops the stack according to the calling convention. ISRs are however not called by the program but by hardware, so they often have a different calling convention. In order to generate these special instructions correctly, you need some non-standard interrupt syntax.

The code is an interrupt vector table, so the type definition is correct. However, in case the ISR is declared as a plain function without any special keywords `void Reset_Handler(void)`, then this won't work. The incorrect cast here `(vect_t) Reset_Handler` will ensure that this function is called upon interrupt, but it will not return from that function correctly - likely crashing.

> My assumption is that __irq should have been used on Reset_Handler (and on all other interrupt handlers) and not in the type definition. Is this correct?

It should be in the vector table and in the ISR function definition both.

Comment: Specifically for ARM Cortex M I believe there's some register "LR" (Link Register) that you must set upon leaving an ISR. It's something you'll want the compiler to do for you, rather than hacking it out manually in asm.

Comment: The cortex-m is designed such that it does not require a special return instruction you build the function according to the normal abi.  so there is no expectation for the functions to appear different.  but as answered here this is the purpose for some compilers to have this directive.   The full sized arms (aarch32) does have a specific return instruction, but it also has other requirements with respect to what gets saved on the stack so the compiler would be expected to handle all of that stack, flags, and return instruction (depending on the architecture)

Comment: the cortex-m logic creates a special, non-valid, return address that the hardware detects to know this bx lr is a return from interrupt/exception.  they push the non-volatile registers (per a convention, known at the time of the architecture design) plus actual return address, etc then leave a bogus (0xFFFFFxxx) return address.

Comment: also no trampoline is needed.  All of these are notes to the op not Lundin, Lundin knows all of these kinds of things.   what you need to know about the cortex-m is in the arm documentation and then experimentally you can see this in action including how the compiler in question uses this directive per target.

Comment: @old_timer When you say "there is no expectation for the functions to appear different" what do you mean? "Regular" functions vs. interrupt handlers?

Comment: See my answer, before asking here you should just try it and post what you find and what is confusing in the question.   cortex-m has no special requirements for irq handling (no state preservation and no special instruction.....by design)

Comment: @Lundin I put the `__irq` on `Reset_Handler`. I tried removing `__irq` from the `typedef` and the compiler failed. It seems that the compiler does treat it as part of the function signature. The error message explicitly mentions that `void (*)(void)__irq` is incompatible with `vect_t` (where `__irq` was removed from `vect_t`).

Comment: @TudorTimi You need to read the compiler docs about how to use it. Or if you mention which compiler you are using, maybe someone can help. Every embedded compiler use slightly different syntax for this but the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Using gcc for example (attributes/directives/pragmas etc are specific to a tool not to the C language)

```
struct interrupt_frame;

__attribute__ ((interrupt))
void x (struct interrupt_frame *frame)
{
}

void y ( void )
{
}
```

Using a generic aarch32 type arm target:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <x>:
   0:   e25ef004    subs    pc, lr, #4

00000004 <y>:
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Now let's complicate this further

```
struct interrupt_frame;

unsigned int k;

__attribute__ ((interrupt))
void x (struct interrupt_frame *frame)
{
    k=5;
}

void y ( void )
{
    k=5;
}

00000000 <x>:
   0:   e92d000c    push    {r2, r3}
   4:   e3a02005    mov r2, #5
   8:   e59f3008    ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; 18 <x+0x18>
   c:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
  10:   e8bd000c    pop {r2, r3}
  14:   e25ef004    subs    pc, lr, #4

0000001c <y>:
  1c:   e3a02005    mov r2, #5
  20:   e59f3004    ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; 2c <y+0x10>
  24:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
  28:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

For an interrupt you need to preserve all the registers in an interrupt, for a regular function the calling convention dictates which registers are volatile within the function.  So with this example you can see the primary reason for the directive, preserve the state and use the specific return from interrupt instruction.

Because the cortex-m architectures (armv6-m, 7-m and 8-m) were designed so that you could put C functions directly in the vector table without any wrapping of asm around them (the hardware takes care of both preserving state and the special return issues).  The compiler generates code the same way, basically the attribute has no effect on that target:

```
00000000 <x>:
   0:   2205        movs    r2, #5
   2:   4b01        ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; (8 <x+0x8>)
   4:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
   6:   4770        bx  lr

0000000c <y>:
   c:   2205        movs    r2, #5
   e:   4b01        ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; (14 <y+0x8>)
  10:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
  12:   4770        bx  lr
```

And the last note is that you do not return from the reset vector so there is no reason for cortex-m to even bother with an attribute/directive like this for the reset vector.  Well no architecture should you return from the reset vector if it is truly a bare-metal vector table (vs using the same scheme for general application entry sitting on an os, not-bare-metal) (or a bootloader calling this code you can certainly return).

Other architectures do not tend to lump reset in the list of "interrupts" or "exceptions" reset is reset, ARM docs and code tend to think of them as any other exception and as a result you have to still think of it differently.

Comment: Note that I dont know nor care what the interrupt_frame is for gcc, not relevant to this answer/topic.   Are you using Kiel?  What did you see when you tried this (for one of the cortex-m targets or any other?)

Comment: Not really what I was asking, but an informative answer nevertheless! The fact that for v6-M it's not important to mark a function as an interrupt handler was a very useful piece of information.

Comment: On exception entry (a real one, not the reset handler), only some state is preserved, though: xPSR, ReturnAddress(), LR 
(R14), R12, R3, R2, R1, and R0. This means, that if the function wants to use R4, for example, that it would have to stack it itself, right?

Comment: Read up a bit more on calling conventions and processor registers. R4-R8 is callee-save, so the compiler would anyway know to stack it before using it.

Comment: yes, just the volatile registers need to be saved, not the callee saved ones (assuming the compiler matches the hardware with respect to the convention, if not then __irq would ideally cover the gap).  (no reason for a compiler to conform to anyone elses convention in general, it is authors choice).